# NodeJS application to use quickbooks Oauth2.0 and stay log in

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I was able to implement a NodeJS application to sign in with my quickbooks developer account using OAuth2.0.I have the client key and the secret key and I am able to get the access token by signing in to quickbooks with their pop up and it redirects me to my application, and then the user is able to send invoices or get data from this quickbooks account.

However, I want the user not to have to sign in to quickbooks in order for it to send invoices or any other operation on quickbooks. I want to be able to write the functionality the application is allow to perform on the QuickbooksAPI by automatically signing in into quickbooks. How can I achieve this?

To word this differently, I want the NodeJS server to log in into quickbooks automatically if application user has the roles or permission to do a quickbooks action, such as creating and invoice or retrieve information. The application should grant itself permission to the OAuth2.0. How do I do this? with a JWT token? Not sure

A bit of background: I was able to accomplish Oauth2.0 authentication by using node-quickbooks by mcohen module.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The application should grant itself permission to the OAuth2.0. How do I do this?

You can't.

But you may also be misunderstanding how OAuth is supposed to work.

You need to have the user go through the OAuth process ONCE. EXACTLY once. Never more than *once*.

Once you have them go through that process *once*, you get back an access token *and* a refresh token.

You can then use those tokens to *get updated tokens* whenever you want (e.g. refresh your access/refresh token programatically, *without* any user interaction at all). See the docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#refresh-the-token

So, have the user go through OAuth once. Then *store the tokens in your app*. Refresh the tokens via the refresh token API. The user just has to auth exactly once, and then everything else you can do automatically forever going forward.

Comment: Hello sir I m following your above link but getting error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870639/error-statuscodeerror-400-error-invalid-grant